# How to find true visible size of a text string in Java

Tags: java, fonts, typography

Is it possible to find the true bounding box of a string in Java? ie the smallest rectangle which includes the pixels which actually get painted?

I have looked at FontMetrics and LineMetrics, and although they allow a string to be passed in, they don't appear to take account of the characters themselves, eh "a", "p" and "P" all return the same height.

Specifically, they seem to include the descent in the string height even if the actual character does not descend below the baseline. Are there other metrics I can access which return a true bounding box?

Alternatively, is there any way to tell if a particular character has a descender?

Comment: Have you checked out the getAscent(), getDescent() and charWidth() methods?  Check out the [FontMetrics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) page for details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this [tutorial on measuring text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html), which is heavily focused on [FontMetrics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html).

The more advanced measurements (to get the bounding box of a particular string), then [TextLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html) is your friend, [as explained here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120625232702/http://java.sun.com:80/developer/onlineTraining/Media/2DText/other.html).

In addition to that tutorial on TextLayout, the javadoc contains examples of its use.

Comment: I have looked at FontMetrics, the problem is that the height() value always seems to include the descent, even for a character like "a". So my box around "a" has extra space underneath the letter.

Comment: Added link to TextLayout tutorial, which I believe handles this.

Comment: In particular TextLayout.getBounds

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javax.swing.SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabel`. Do not be deterred by the many parameters. There are two versions, the version with the JComponent (may be null) does more flags. It is used for JLabel, so quite versatile, and yields a Rectangle.

BTW That even on "a" a descender might be added to the bounds, is likely to happen here too. You could take the GlyphVector and calculate a bounding box there, but what when font hinting is on, so the pixel positions are slightly off, which error might accumulate over several chars?